# Iam not getting iOS verions 6.0 how do i get this?

Tags: xcode

I have Xcode version is 4.3.2 and it showing Deployment Target max is 5.1 now how do i have to get 6.0?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an IOS developer, but it looks to me like you need XCode 4.5 to develop IOS 6 apps:

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

Comment: This is correct. In essence, Apple is forcing developers to use the latest version of their tools, which is a good thing. Although you don't actually need to target iOS 6.0 unless you have a specific requirement for that.